# Cakephp images upload

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp Qimage component for image uploads.

```
public  function img_uploads(){
    $data['file']= $this->request->data['Basicprofile']['photo'];
    $data['path']= WWW_ROOT . 'img/uploads/teachers/';
    unset($this->request->data['Basicprofile']['photo']);
    $this->request->data['Basicprofile']['photo']=$this->Qimage->copy($data);
}
```

//Qimage Copy Function

```
public function copy($data){

    // Verify file and path
    if (!isset($data['file']) || !isset($data['path']) || !is_array($data['file'])){
        $this->errors[] = 'Name or path not found!';
        return false;
    }

    if (!is_writable($data['path'])){
        $this->errors[] = 'Destination path is not writable!';
        return false;
    }

    if (!$this->_verifyMime($data['file']['name'])){
        $this->errors[] = 'The file must be an jpg, gif or png image!';
        return false;
    }

    // Generate filename and move file to destination path
    $filename_array = explode('.', $data['file']['name']);
    $ext = end($filename_array);
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    $name = uniqid() . date('dmYHis') . '.' . $ext;
    $complete_path = $data['path'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name;

    if (!move_uploaded_file($data['file']['tmp_name'], $data['path'] . $name)){
        $this->errors[] = 'Error while upload the image!';
        return false;
    }

    // Return image filename
    return $name;
}
```

The problem is that the path is not writable. I gave the permission 777 to uploads folder. Still images are not uploading. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is OS that you use?

Comment: Is the path correct? i.e. is WWW_ROOT properly configured to go to the right directory?  Also, you say you have 777 permissions to the upload folder, but is the teachers folder also writable?

Comment: You are right  @gabe3886 . teachers folder was not writable. Thank you for your suggestion. Its working

Comment: I am using linux  @u2460470. Thanks !!! problem is solved